# Duplicate content after author leaves my site to self-host his blog

Tags: duplicate-content

I understand this question is asked frequently but my case is slightly different.

I work for a website allowing users to have their own blogs and it might happen that one of the authors might decide to leave my website to self-host his blog.

I want to take a friendly approach when this happens, that is, I will help the blogger in the export/import of data.

But what about duplicate content issues? If the blogger published 100 articles on my website, 100 links will be duplicated on two domains, mine and his:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blogger/blog-name/article
```

and

```
http://www.bloggersdomain.com/article
```

How shall I tackle this problem? I mean both URLs will have the same, exact content and that is because I will not remove the articles from my website.

Will I be penalized by Google because of duplicate content?

Comment: What is the problem as you see it? Are you wanting to keep this traffic? Or are you wanting to help the blog authors new site?

Comment: Apologies for not making myself clear. The problem is that both URLs will have the same, exact content and that is because I will not remove the articles from my website. I might be penalized by Google because of duplicate content, no?

Comment: No, you won't be "penalized" for duplicate content. When Google finds two pages the same (duplicate content), Google is likely to only return one of the pages in the SERPs - that is the only problem. The fact that your site is where the article was first published, is already indexed(?) and perhaps has inbound links(?) is likely to be seen as the authoritative page and is more likely to appear in the SERPs (at least in the short term). The `bloggersdomain` is likely to have the harder task of getting indexed for this reason, unless you are willing to set up 301 redirects to their new site?

Comment: Ah, great. No, I don't want to 301, I want to keep the articles on my domain and having my pages as the authoritative ones. Please post comment as answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what about duplicate content issues?

As mentioned in comments, this should not be a problem for you - you won't get "penalized" for duplicate content.

When Google finds two pages the same (duplicate content), Google is likely to only return one of the pages in the SERPs - that is the only problem - the page that doesn't appear is not penalized as such, it is simply not ranking higher than the other page.

The fact that your site is where the article was first published, is already indexed(?) and perhaps has inbound links(?) is likely to be seen as the authoritative page and is more likely to appear in the SERPs (at least in the short term). In fact, the new `bloggersdomain` is likely to have the harder task of getting indexed for this reason, unless you are willing to set up 301 redirects to their new site?